# Serialize custom object produce file with missed info

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I have issue. When I try to `serialize` list of my custom object all my info is missed.

My output of serialization:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <ArrayOfCustomObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CustomObject /> 
  <CustomObject /> 
  <CustomObject /> 
  </ArrayOfCustomObject>
```

I have some code demonstrating my serialization approach:

```
Dim xmlSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of CustomObject )))

Using fileStrm As New StreamWriter("C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\xmlTest.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
   xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStrm, objectsList)
End Using
```

Where CustomObject is:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRootAttribute("SomeObject")>
Public Class CustomObject 

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal someTable As DataTable, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal title As String)
        _someTable = someTable 
        _title = title
        _id = id
    End Sub

    Private _someTable As DataTable
    Private _title As String
    Private _id As Integer

    <XmlAttribute("Title")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("Table")>
    Public ReadOnly Property SomeTable As DataTable
        Get
            Return _someTable 
        End Get
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("ID")>
    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Where can be my mistakes? (If c# is more appropriate fell free to answer with it)

Comment: you have forget to provide extension to stream writer C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\xmlTest

Comment: @Terror.Blade tnxs for comment, but this is not a reason of my issue. I edited this code manually and just miss extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` will ignore properties without setter.

In your case this property, for example, will be ignored:

```
<XmlAttribute("Table")>
Public ReadOnly Property SomeTable As DataTable
    Get
        Return _someTable 
    End Get
End Property
```

Because it's read-only: serializer is designed to work on both direction then it's meaningless (from its point of view) to serialize something it won't be able to deserialize later.

There are many reasons it'll ignore a property (see MSDN for details, list is pretty long and not always so obvious). What you *may* do if you want to keep `XmlSerializer` is to add a setter method or to create a special object (a surrogate, similar to what `BinarySerializer` does) for deserialization with properties forwarded to your current object:

```
<XmlRootAttribute("SomeObject")>
Public Class CustomObjectSurrogate

    Sub New()
        ' Uncomment this if you plan to support deserialization too
        ' _realObject = New CustomObject()
    End Sub

    Sub New(realObject As CustomObject)
        _realObject = realObject
    End Sub

    Private _realObject As CustomObject

    <XmlAttribute("Table")>
    Public Property SomeTable As DataTable
        Get
            Return _realObject.SomeTable 
        End Get
        Set(value As DataTable)
            ' Ignore, this is a dummy object for serialization
        End Set
    End Property

    ' More properties here
End Class
```

With this you'll serialize `CustomObjectSurrogagte` (nothing more than a thin wrapper to access `CustomObject` properties). In this way you can keep `CustomObject` implementation as much clean as you want.

Well, of course you can always implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface to force `XmlSerializer` to do exactly what you want but it may require a lot of work (especially if serialized interface may/will differ a lot to current object model).

I love *surragte* solution especially because (without all the dirty work of `IXmlSerializable`) allows me to serialize (and eventually deserialize) something different (I'm thinking, for example, about dictionaries, generic collections and dates). Make `CustomObjectSurrogate` a nested class inside `CustomObject` and you won't even need to have a public setter for `CustomObject` properties.